# LINQ get rows from a table that don't exist in another table when using group by?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two three tables books, authors and groups.

books: bookId, name, authorId....

authors: authorId, firstName, LastName....

groups: groupID, name, authorId...

i need to select all `authorIds` that doesn't belong to any groups and doesn't have less than 3 books published between two dates.

```
 List<int> authorId= new List<int>(db.Books.GroupBy(x => x.authorId)
                .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.datePublished <= now && y.datePublished >= date) && x.Count() > 2)
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().authorId)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: From your code snippet are we safe to assume that datePublished is in 'Books'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this would work:

```
List<int> authorId = (List<int>)db.Books
    .Where(x => x.datePublished >= InitialDate)
    .Where(x => x.datePublished <= FinalDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.authorId)
    .Select(g => new { authorId = g.Key, count = g.Count() })
    .Where(g => g.Count >= 3)
    .Select(g.authorId);
```

I make every single step so you can see it better, fell free to optimized as needed. The key thing here is the `new { authorId = g.Key, count = g.Count() }`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming that you're using Entity Framework and you have the proper [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) in your model, you can do something like this:

```
var authorIds= db.Authors
                 .Where(a=>a.Books.Count(y => y.datePublished <= now && y.datePublished >= date)>2 && !a.Groups.Any())
                 .ToList();
```

Another solution that came to my mind now but I'm not sure if it works is using two [group joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx):

```
var authorId=(from a in db.Authors
              join b in db.Books on a.authorId equals b.authorId into g1
              join g in db.Groups on a.authorId equals g.authorId into g2
              where  g1.Count(y => y.datePublished <= now && y.datePublished >= date)>0 && !g2.Any()
              select a.authorId).ToList();
```

But I definitely prefer my first solution, it's more readable and easy too.

Comment: Basically exactly what I was thinking. The only suggestion is to use `&& !a.Groups.Any()` for clarity and performance. +1

Comment: Yours is a preferable solution for me. My solution is just assuming @usesser must get it from `db.Books`.