# Entity Framework Core Count unrelated records in another table

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I need to count how many records in the tableA are not in the tableA, how to do this with LINQ?

with SQL I do the following way

```
select count(*) as total from produtoitemgrade g
where g.id not in (select idprodutograde from produtoestoque where idProduto = 12)
and g.idProduto = 12
```

my linq code so far.

```
 var temp = (from a in Produtoitemgrades
              join b in Produtoestoques on a.IdUnico equals b.IdUnicoGrade into g1
              where g1.Count(y => y.IdProduto == 12)>0 && !g1.Any()
              select a).ToList();
```

I tried to follow that example [LINQ get rows from a table that don't exist in another table when using group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312644/linq-get-rows-from-a-table-that-dont-exist-in-another-table-when-using-group-by)

but an error occurs when running, how can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should looks like the following, if you want to have the same SQL execution plan:

```cs
var query = 
   from a in Produtoitemgrades
   where !Produtoestoques.Where(b => a.IdUnico == b.IdUnicoGrade && b.idProduto == 12).Any() 
     && a.idProduto == 12
   select a;

var result = query.Count();
```